# I am unable to create a pex file with a custom pacakge inside

Tags: python-3.x, package, python-3.10, pex

I was following [this](https://medium.com/ovni/pex-python-executables-c0ea39cee7f1) tutorial to add my own pacakge to .pex but this tutorial is based on python2 and I try to recreate for python3.10.6 but does not works.
The structure of my package is as follow hello/**init**.py , hello/hello.py , hello/setup.py

[image: hello/init.py , hello/hello.py , hello/setup.py]

**init**.py (empty)

hello.py:

```
    def hello(): 
       print("hello!")
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup( name='hello', version='0.0.1', py_modules=['hello'] )
```

But when I try to build the pex file follow error is shown:
[image]

```
$ pex hello -e hello:hello -o hello.pex
pid 282 -> /home/leraes93/.pex/venvs/607954d150b1247ce7c1a15f91d4c7d23be98298/5985ed09b49a653d6596b0e14d134c5456cf1a9f/bin/python -sE /home/leraes93/.pex/venvs/607954d150b1247ce7c1a15f91d4c7d23be98298/5985ed09b49a653d6596b0e14d134c5456cf1a9f/pex --disable-pip-version-check --no-python-version-warning --exists-action a --no-input --use-deprecated legacy-resolver --isolated -q --cache-dir /home/leraes93/.pex/pip_cache download --dest /home/leraes93/.pex/downloads/resolver_download.dbt8psp4/mnt.c.Users.PC.Documents.env_medical_app.bin.python3 hello --index-url https://pypi.org/simple 
--retries 5 --timeout 15 exited with 1 and STDERR:
Re-execing from /home/leraes93/.pex/venvs/607954d150b1247ce7c1a15f91d4c7d23be98298/5985ed09b49a653d6596b0e14d134c5456cf1a9f/bin/python
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hello (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-------How to run a .pex file:-----------
First install follow libraries (if bdist_wheel is not able to install skip that step)

- pip install wheel
- pip install pex
- pip install bdist_wheel
- python setup.py bdist_wheel
- export PYTHON_ENTRYPOINT=package.my_package
- pex --disable-cache . -e ${PYTHON_ENTRYPOINT} -o app.pex (in

For run just run follow command: './app.pex'

Herachy of folders:
setup.py
-----
`import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
APP_VERSION = os.environ.get("APP_VERSION", '0.0.0')
APP_NAME = os.environ.get("APP_NAME", "api-name")

```
def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    version=APP_VERSION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={"": ["setup.cfg"]},
    include_package_data=True
)`
```

setup.cfg
-----
[pycodestyle]
max-line-length = 200
ignore = W605,E402,E713,E712

```
--- package
    --- my_package.py
        ---def my_function():
                print('hello')
           my_function()
    --- __init__.py
--- setup.py
--- setup.cfg
```